# How to specify generic class within where clause of a generic?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

I have the following classes and method:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T>
    where T : class
{
}

public class MyClass
{
    public TGen MyMethod<TGen>(TGen myGenClass)
        where TGen : MyGenericClass<T>
        where T : class
    {
        return myGenClass;
    }
}
```

However, this gives an error because it cannot resolve the symbol `T` in MyMethod. I would prefer to not have to have `MyMethod<TGen, T>` since it seems a bit redundant to me. Is this possible?

Comment: But there is no `T` type parameter in `MyMethod`.  I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I would like to have something like `public TGen MyMethod<TGen>(TGen myGenClass) where TGen : MyGenericClass<>`

Comment: Again, I don't understand what you're trying to convey with `MyGenericClass<>`.  Why do you think that the type parameter to `MyGenericClass` would be inferred in any way?  Inferred to what?

Comment: What is the reason to avoid `MyMethod<TGen, T>` - it only need to appear in the method declaration, but not when you call it. So why you want to fight with language syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to use *any* `MyGenericClass` implementation for your `TGen` type, then you will need to create a base class of the `MyGenericClass` implementation to use (of course, this limits what functionality you will get for your `TGen` instance.

```
 public class MyGenericClassBase { }
 public class MyGenericClass<T> : MyGenericClassBase { }
 public class MyClass<TGen> 
      where TGen: MyGenericClassBase
 {
     // Stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify `T` before you can use it in a definition. There is no way for the compiler to know what `T` is.

So you should specify `T` before you use it (at method level as below, or perhaps at class level with `MyClass`):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public TGen MyMethod<TGen, T>(TGen myGenClass)
        where TGen : MyGenericClass<T>
        where T : class
    {
        return myGenClass;
    }
}
```

You can also use a concrete implementation of the generic type in the where clause:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public TGen MyMethod<TGen>(TGen myGenClass)
        where TGen : MyGenericClass<DateTime>
    {
        return myGenClass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're just forgetting to include `T` in the list of generic types for the method:

```
public TGen MyMethod<TGen, T>(TGen myGenClass)
    where TGen : MyGenericClass<T>
    where T : class
{
    return myGenClass;
}
```